# Issues of padding-bottom when an element is below a div

Tags: html, css, web, padding

Heys guys. I've made a simple sample of a problem that has had me stumped for a long time - the code below has no purpose at all, it just shows the problem in a more legible way.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="teste.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <span>
      Palavra       
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background-color: #5959AB;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

So, I tried to make "Palavra" go up by adding a padding-bottom to it:

```
span {
  padding-bottom: 2000px;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

"Palavra" just stays at the same precise position but a vertical scrolling bar appeared. It seems that "Palavra" is pushing down it's bottom part because it just can't go up from where it is.

This problem is appearing for me in so many ways that my mind is already blowing - can someone please help?

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Try to put "palavra" on the purple bar.

Comment: This is basic CSS that can be solved with a simple google search. Add a negative `margin-top` to the span.

Comment: I know it works. My doubt is why "padding-bottom" does not works; Google didn't return anything about that, specifically.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question either. You are expecting `padding-bottom` to push up the element once the padding reaches the bottom of the window? If so, you might want to start looking into HTML box model. What you are seeing is the appropriate behavior for an element.

Comment: If you want "Palavra" to be 'on' the purple bar, you should nest the `<span>` inside the `<div>` - this is basic markup. Though, if you do this, you'll need to update the `color` property of the `span`; the black font color will not sit well on that purple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 good ways to position the span.

1. You can make it display:block, and use a negative top margin as Lloyd Banks describes. The span needs to change from the default inline element to a block element because the top margin does not work with inline elements, but it does work with block elements.

From W3C ["Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. ... These properties apply to all elements, but **vertical margins will not have any effect on** non-replaced **inline elements**."](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-margin-area)

With this technique, you'll need a z-index on the div and span, so the span will be on top of the div, and not slide underneath it. [MDN z-index article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/pwrpp9cc/)

```
#bar {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#5959AB;
    color:white;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:150%;
    font-weight:bold;
    z-index:1;
}

span{
    position:relative;
    display:block;    
    margin-top:-25px;
    z-index:2;    
}
```

---

2. The second way is to absolutely position the span so it will be pulled out of the document flow, and placed at the top of its container.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/b75rnvzd/)

```
span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
   }
```

---

Adding padding to the bottom of the span will increase the size/length of the span by adding space to the bottom only. It will not push the span up from its original location, but it will push elements below it further down the page (because the span is now larger).

When you added 2000px bottom padding to the span, it was over 2000px tall, and was taller than your browser window, thus causing the scrollbar. Adding a background color to your element is a good way to see how padding and sizing work.

Here's a good detailed article from W3C on the box model including margins and padding http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-margin-area

And here is an easy article with a "Try it yourself" example:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: negative value for ``margin-top`` fixed a very vexing css issue for me and I am grateful for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your `span` `display: block`

Then use a negative `margin-top` value

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/as7ow9yr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You should rather write 'Palavra' in the div itself.

```
<div id="bar">
     <span>
      Palavra       
      </span>  
 </div>
```

Once you close the  tag the  will start from the very next line.

Moreover, If you want to take the content upward you have to work with the **padding-top** not the bottom one ! But, this will not help you taking your content into the  as  starts after the .

By adding padding-bottom you are increasing the size of the CSS box as per the Box model which is worthless here!

Comment: user3708854 : Obviously, padding-bottom will not help you. Instead you try to lessen the padding-top.
Go to the link and try to increase the paddin-bottom there, you will get your answer !
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_padding_shorthand